# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webbrowser' when trying to start jupyter notebook in pycharm

Tags: python, jupyter

when I try to start a jupyter notebook in pycharm on the local host I get the above written error. I tried to `pip install webbrowser` but it said

> "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webbrowser
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for webbrowser"

Also webbrowser should be there by default I guess. 
I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: Maybe `webbrowser` is disabled because it would open a browser on the server, not the client. What would you expect it to do?

Comment: @PeterWood I am completely new to Jupyter so I don't really know what it is supposed to do. The steps I am following are:
I create a new notebook file in PyCharm, I enter a print argument into the first cell, I run it, a window pops up that says "Jupyter Notebook URL" and per default "http://127.0.0.1:8888" is in there. When I press okay, the Error occurs. I guess it is trying to open my browser, not sure why it doesnt work